# Acumatica and SQL Monitoring and APM Software suggestion

Tags: acumatica

We are looking into options to monitor our Acumatica instance to identify performance issues on the application level as well as the SQL server level. We have experience with newrelic and a few others, but also read about Retrace (https://stackify.com/retrace/) which looks worth trying.

I'm curious to know if it's possible/recommended to install such tools within Acumatica?

Does anyone have any experience or feedback on the topic?

Answer (score 0):

Acumatica includes a built-in request profiler that can be used to monitor requests, performance and SQL. Probably not as sophisticated as New Relic, but powerful enough when you have performance issues to resolve. Read more here: https://help-2017r2.acumatica.com/(W(2))/Wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?wikiname=HelpRoot_User&PageID=e7612f3f-fc6f-494d-8532-cc2ceef7147b